Why am I reading 69 volts across the terminals on my outlet?
I have three receptacles and one light tied to one AFGCI breaker. When I measure across the neutral and “hot” terminals of the receptacles and light, I measure 69 volts. When I measure from the “hot” terminal to ground, I measure 125 volts on all the devices. I measured across the terminals of the breaker, I measured 125 volts BUT I have two neutral wires going to this breaker for some reason. I am assuming one of the neutrals going to the breaker is bad.

you lost the neutral

This might be "neutral from load to breaker" + "neutral from breaker to panel", which is normal for AFCI/GFCI breaker on a non-plug-on-neutral panel. Pictures of the panel would help.


If there are other outlets with a similar issue, the mains neutral wire is broken -- fix ASAP to avoid shock and/or fire. 2. With breaker off: If the receptacle has wires poked into the "stab" connectors, try stripping farther and using the screw terminals.


Is there a problem with the light/receptacle?  Is the light dim or too bright, does stuff work normally when plugged in?  The reason for you to test might help.

Based on only the information you have given. If you are reading 69V from hot to neutral, and 125V from hot to ground. It is indicative of a loose connection somewhere in the neutral conductor. It could be at a terminal or it could be at a splice. You probably need to go through the entire circuit and check all connections. This is a problem because low voltage like this will heat up underload and will cause damage and possible fire. This was quite common during the aluminum wire days.
If you have an ohm meter you can verify this by checking the resistance of the  circuit. Make sure the switch to the light is in the off position.
